# How to capture identical groups along with non identical groups

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

I am trying to capture two types of comments in the code. Comments are of type /*..*/ and //...

My pattern: r'(/*.*?*/)|(//.*?)/'

The above pattern doesn't capture two similar multiline comment group(/**/). if they are separated by a single line comment group (//...).

What is wrong with this pattern?

```
p=re.compile(r'(/\*.*?\*/)|(//.*?)/')
s='/*first multiline*/ //other comment /*second multiline*/'

expected:
["/*first multiline*/",""]
["","//other comment "]
["/*second multiline*/",""]

Actual:
["/*first multiline*/",""]
["","//other comment "]
```

note: i know this will not work for the comments which span multiple lines. I just want to understand the problem with the above pattern for the given input

Comment: Try `re.split(r'\s*(/\*+[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/)\s*', s)` to tokenize a string into multiline  comments and everything else.

Comment: this looks like another solution. I want to know where am i going wrong in the above pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

`re.compile(r'(/\*.*?\*/)|(//[^/\r\n]+)', re.DOTALL)`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/T4cM98/3

The problem was your last slash after the second capturing group took up the first slash of your supposed match:

```
r'(/\*.*?\*/)|(//.*?)/'
                     ^ here
```

Once that slash is removed however, due to the non-greedy `?` notation it will not capture anything further than the double `//`, so just match everything that is not a `/` after the `//`.

Edit: Updated with `//[^/\r\n]+` and re.DOTALL as suggested by Wiktor.

Comment: The `//[^/]+` won't work in general case, as `[^/]` matches newlines, too, but it is supposed to match *single-line* comments. `/\*.*?\*/` won't work as it should match across lines and you have no flag set.

Comment: Would `//[^/\n]+` be a better alternative then?

Comment: Yes, adding a newline would fix that, CR can be added, too. Together with `(?s)` DOTALL flag before the multiline comment pattern.

Comment: Updated with the `\r\n` as well as `re.DOTALL` flag. Thanks for your suggestion!